# Revit, Using Python, Can't get the Family "Type Names" for a Family, Just the ID

Tags: python, revit

I've tried for hours to attempt to solve this myself so I can learn.  I'm able to get the Family I want out of Revit (called familyToUpdate) and list the family (symbol) types, but I can't get the type name itself only their ID's.  I want to compare the actual Type Name against a text parameter I called (typeToDelete) so that I can delete only the types I know are not being used.  I've been through numerous examples but can never get them to work.

Here is my code to date:

```
import Autodesk.Revit.DB as DB
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
app = doc.Application

familyToUpdate = "MyFamily"
typeToDelete = "MyFamilyType"

print "Family Name = " + familyToUpdate
print "Type To Delete = " + typeToDelete

#Delete Family Type
Elements = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family).ToElements()

for m in Elements:
    try:
        if m.Name.startswith((familyToUpdate)):
            symbols = list(m.GetFamilySymbolIds())
            for i in symbols:
                print "Family Type Id =  " + str(i)
                famsymbol = doc.GetElement(i)
                print "famsymbol = " + str(famsymbol)
                #symbolName = famsymbol.Family.Name
                #print symbolName
                #if symbolName == typeToDelete:
                #    print "I found the type name"

    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered it myself.  Work on it for hours, then FINALLY post a question.  Take one more look at it, and there it is!!!

Here's the code for anyone else in the future fumbling through what I did:

```
import Autodesk.Revit.DB as DB
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
app = doc.Application

familyToUpdate = "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (PIN07)"
typeToDelete = "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (PIN07) (Hagerman)"

print "Family Name = " + familyToUpdate
print "Type To Delete = " + typeToDelete + "\n\n"

#Delete Family Type
Elements = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family).ToElements()

for m in Elements:
    try:
        if m.Name.startswith((familyToUpdate)):
            symbols = list(m.GetFamilySymbolIds())
            for i in symbols:
                #print "Family Type Id =  " + str(i)
                famsymbol = doc.GetElement(i)
                #print "Symbol ID = " + str(famsymbol)
                symbolName = famsymbol.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.SYMBOL_NAME_PARAM).AsString()
                print "SymbolName = " + symbolName

    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the solution. In it, you are retrieving the symbol name from the `SYMBOL_NAME_PARAM` built-in parameter. That is perfectly valid. An easier and more direct way to read the symbol name is to simply query the [Element.Name property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/e372092e-ff47-71c2-1272-50ab08e5a41d.htm). `Element` is the parent class of all Revit database resident objects, including `FamilySymbol`.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for the info.  I thought I tried that, but I may have messed something up.  I'll go back and give it a go.  Appreciate the suggestion and all of your resources you have available - it's a big help!

Answer (score 0):

Element.Name will not work because of multi-level inheritance. try the following instead:

```
name = Element.Name.GetValue(familysymbol)
```